# Creating an Interactive map using an Image not google map

Tags: android, iphone, image, static, dictionary

I want to create a map view using a static image, so I can enlarge the image, minimize it, and if I click on a specific place on the image a message with the clicked place name appear. **I'm using titanium for android and iPhone**. Is it possible?

Note that I create this map but the problem I have that if I click on the image after enlarge it the message that appear will not be correct because the x and y will differ.

I need to enlarge the image cause it contain very small building.

I hope my Question is clear.

Comment: Maybe HTML map  with jQuery will help?

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a scaling factor so that when you increase the image size you can apply the scaling factor to the clicked x and y coordinates which should give you what they would have been on the original image, and then use those when retrieving your message.

if you can pan the image, then you will also need to introduce a panning factor also.

Comment: thanks for your answer..
I think about it but the problem is how do I know the zoom scale itself? look at Prateek Raj Question on zooming a view I tried it but when I add ImageView the image will not scale until I give it property canScale = true ...
My question is close to him cause when I specify the x and y I add a view on a specific location and with listener to display message.
but if I scale the image those views will not scale with it. I need either one of these solutions:- try to get the scalefactor and update x & y -make all the views scale together..
I hope I describe my problem well